# php array function solution

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [vd] => Array
        (
            [deal_id] => 811
            [settlement_dt] => 2013-01-16 00:00:00
            [pricing_dt] => 2013-01-08 00:00:00
            [maturity_dt] => 2022-07-25 00:00:00
        )

    [market] => Array
        (
            [market_type_desc] => Public
        )

    [issue] => Array
        (
            [issue_type_desc] => Kangaroo
        )

)
```

i want this in format:

```
Array
(   
            [deal_id] => 811
            [settlement_dt] => 2013-01-16 00:00:00
            [pricing_dt] => 2013-01-08 00:00:00
            [maturity_dt] => 2022-07-25 00:00:00     
            [market_type_desc] => Public
        [issue_type_desc] => Kangaroo
)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### A one-liner

```
$new_arr = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/143002)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entire array is $your_array...

`array_merge( $your_array['vd'], $your_array['market'], $your_array['issue'] );`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be more branches, you can join them all automatically:

```
$array = [....];
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k => $a)
{
    if(is_array($a)) $result = array_merge($result, $a);
        else $result[$ka] = $a;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it helps you.

```
$oldArray = Array
(
    'vd' => Array
    (
        'deal_id' => '811',
        'settlement_dt' => '2013-01-16 00:00:00',
        'pricing_dt' => '2013-01-08 00:00:00',
        'maturity_dt' => '2022-07-25 00:00:00',
    ),

    'market' => Array
    (
        'market_type_desc' => 'Public'
    ),

    'issue' => Array
    (
        'issue_type_desc' => 'Kangaroo'
    )

);

$newArray = array();

$newArray = array_merge($oldArray['vd'], $newArray);
$newArray = array_merge($oldArray['market'], $newArray);
$newArray = array_merge($oldArray['issue'], $newArray);
```

$newArray contains the values you need.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

```
$initialArray = Array
(
    'vd' => Array
        ( 'deal_id' =>'811', 'settlement_dt' =>'2013-01-16 00:00:00', 'pricing_dt' => '2013-01-08 00:00:00', 'maturity_dt' => '2022-07-25 00:00:00'
        ),

    'market' => Array
        ( 'market_type_desc' => 'Public' ),

    'issue' => Array
        ( 'issue_type_desc' => 'Kangaroo' )
);

$finalArray = array();
$finalArray = array_merge($initialArray['vd'],$finalArray);
$finalArray = array_merge($initialArray['market'],$finalArray);
$finalArray = array_merge($initialArray['issue'],$finalArray);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalArray);
```

**Output will be:**

```
Array
(
    [issue_type_desc] => Kangaroo
    [market_type_desc] => Public
    [deal_id] => 811
    [settlement_dt] => 2013-01-16 00:00:00
    [pricing_dt] => 2013-01-08 00:00:00
    [maturity_dt] => 2022-07-25 00:00:00
)
```